# servicemonitor doesnot add to prometheus-operator targets

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator, servicemonitor

I have deployed a Prometheus-operator on the k8s cluster.
Everything works well but I want to monitor MySQL pods that are in another namespace.
I create mysqld-exporter pod and svc for it in MariaDB namespace and a servicemonitor for it in the monitoring namespace.
I check all the items which are in this [link](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting-servicemonitor-changes), but this servicemonitor(for mysqld) doesn't add to Prometheus targets.
when I change the svc type to nodeport everything works, and metrics are exposed.

```html
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-11T11:51:46Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 9.1.2
    monitor-app: mysqld-exporter
  name: mysqld-exporter
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "2932040"
  uid: 247683c8-7868-4f2c-9a60-255c703273a5
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    port: http-metrics
  jobLabel: k8s-app
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - mariadb
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysqld-exporter


--------

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-11T11:50:28Z"
  labels:
    app: mysqld-exporter
  name: mysqld-exporter
  namespace: mariadb
  resourceVersion: "2931235"
  uid: 1b548f89-33a1-4235-b042-8cda5dfc766b
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.109.39.231
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.109.39.231
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http-metrics
    port: 9104
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9104
  selector:
    app: mysqld-exporter
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but monitoring, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, I will ask my question on these sites that you told.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Prometheus pod logs, and its error was :

> pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:monitoring:prometheus-k8s" cannot list resource

so I search for this error and find the answer in [this](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/483#issuecomment-610427646) link and add pods and services to the resources of Prometheus-k8s ClusterRole.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and modifying the clusterRole permissions as per the above link https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/483#issuecomment-610427646   solved this issue for me. Now Prometheus can scrape from pods in another namespace.